# Cheap hotels with family rooms near motorways in France

Tags: europe, france, hotels, family

I am driving to France with my family, so we will be 2 adults, 2 children and one infant. I guess we need a family 4 person room, because the infant can either use a travel cot or share the bed with the adults. Previously we used the F1 hotels, but they only have triple rooms. What would be an alternative budget chain of hotels that offers rooms for my family?

Comment: Ibis Budget is one that springs to mind, but I'm not sure if they'd have suitable rooms or not?

Comment: @Gagravarr, from a quick search it seems that Ibis Budget also doesn't have rooms for 4 people.

Comment: [There's a recent Daily Telegraph article here](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/travel/730804/The-Sophie-Butler-report-Overnight-stops-in-France.html) which gives some more options, but I've not tried the others listed so I can't comment on their suitability

Answer (score 2):

On Akena hotels website ( http://www.hotels-akena.com/fr/carte-generale.html ) they claim that some of their hotels have some 4 person room. It is worth having a look ;)

Answer (score 2):

Late answer but maybe still helpful: http://hotelbb.com/en/home.htm

We use this chain for more than 10 years now to sleep either a single night while going somewhere but also a whole week at one place.

Reasonable priced, available almost every city, close to motorway, shopping and filling station. It is not a luxurius stay (no pool, gym, bar) but we were never disappointed for tidyness or anything!
They offer 2 and 4 bed rooms, and smoking or non-smoking rooms. At least in the places I booked with them before.

In fact, this has become our first check when figuring out where to sleep. Only when unavailable I check others.

Answer (score 0):

Can we assume that this is a stay just overnight while on the road.

The majority of the budget chain hotels are rather standardized, and, as you have seen, family rooms are rare. You might consider two rooms en suite instead.

For stays from 3, maybe 2 nights on, you might consider vacation apartments, which you might find on Gîtes de France or Homelydays. If you are travelling off-season, it may be worthwile to contact the owner if short term rentals are acceptable.